# What is the correct way of doing a small multiples bar chart set in d3 v5?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to finish a small multiples series of some bar charts and I'm missing the final detail in order for them to render correctly. The problem right now is that it is not rendering all the values that the bar chart is expecting and I can't figure out the problem with the code.

here is my csv file:

```
media_outlet,positive,negative,balanced,informational,total
La Opinión,149,296,142,101,688
Wall Street Journal,137,118,125,79,459
Univision,226,484,225,159,1094
San Diego Union Tribune,60,24,18,17,119
Fox News,73,102,58,60,293
Washington Post,52,97,56,50,255
CNN,127,160,102,88,477
USA Today,32,23,14,22,91
The Daily Beast,9,50,13,10,82
Bloomberg,251,183,158,119,711
Fusion,48,86,54,49,237
NPR,20,30,12,14,76
Dallas Morning News,40,34,24,31,129
TIME,26,30,17,17,90
Forbes,97,56,72,37,262
Christian Science Monitor,19,15,21,7,62
NBC News,23,34,19,22,98
Huffington Post,232,344,219,85,880
New York TImes,90,129,74,62,355
Houston Chronicle,40,32,31,24,127
Los Angeles Times,66,75,45,45,231
San Antonio Express News,28,22,14,16,80
Arizona Daily Star,32,15,6,8,61
Vice News,17,169,44,12,242
```

And here is the code I'm writing in order to render the small multiples:

```
d3.csv('../data/media_tendency.csv')
  .then(function(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.positive = +d.positive;
      d.negative = +d.negative;
      d.balanced = +d.balanced;
      d.informational = +d.informational;
      d.total = +d.total;
    });
    //console.log(data);

    outlets(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

function outlets(newsData) {
  //console.log(newsData);

  const data = newsData.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.total < b.total) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  });

  //console.log(data);

  const groups = d3
    .nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.media_outlet;
    })
    .entries(data);

  console.log(groups);

  const colors = ['#5cdacc', '#ff1d34', '#ffc750', '#ff8c50'];

  const margin = { top: 40, right: 50, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
  const width = 310 - margin.left - margin.right;
  const height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const svgs = d3
    .select('#outlets-viz')
    .selectAll('svg')
    .data(groups)
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'media-svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  const tValues = ['P', 'N', 'B', 'I'];

  const color = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(tValues)
    .range(['#5cdacc', '#ff1d34', '#ffc750', '#ff8c50']);

  const x = d3
    .scalePoint()
    .domain(tValues)
    .range([0, width]);
  svgs
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .attr('class', 'domain')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  const max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return +d.total;
  });
  console.log(max);

  const y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([height, 0]);

  const bars = svgs
    .selectAll('.bars')
    .data(function(d) {
      console.log(d.values);
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bars')
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return i * 5;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d, i) {
      return height - y(+d.total);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return y(+d.total);
    })
    .style('fill', function(d, i) {
      return color(d.key);
    });

}
```

The console is not giving back any errors and I'm able to see one bar being drawn, which I assume it's the bar for the positive results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I've been looking for some answers in the d3 blocks but I haven't been able to work my way around them since I have started coding a few months ago.

Thank you for your help :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd spend a bit more time organizing my data up-front to make it simpler when passed to `d3`, something like this:

```
  // loop data once and organize
  let max = -1e9;
  data = data.map(function(d) {
    let m = Math.max(d.positive, d.negative, d.balanced, d.informational);
    if (m > max) max = m; // find max of data
    return {
      key: d.media_outlet,
      values: [{
        key: 'positive',
        value: +d.positive
      }, {
        key: 'negative',
        value: +d.negative
      }, {
        key: 'balanced',
        value: +d.balanced
      }, {
        key: 'informational',
        value: +d.informational
      }]
    };
  });
```

This then becomes a very straight forward `d3` sub-selection to draw the bars:

```
  const bars = svgs
    .selectAll('.bars')
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bars')
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return x(d.key) - 5;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d, i) {
      return height - y(d.value);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .style('fill', function(d, i) {
      return color(d.key);
    });
```

Full running code:

```js
      let newsData = [{
        "media_outlet": "La Opinión",
        "positive": "149",
        "negative": "296",
        "balanced": "142",
        "informational": "101",
        "total": "688"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Wall Street Journal",
        "positive": "137",
        "negative": "118",
        "balanced": "125",
        "informational": "79",
        "total": "459"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Univision",
        "positive": "226",
        "negative": "484",
        "balanced": "225",
        "informational": "159",
        "total": "1094"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "San Diego Union Tribune",
        "positive": "60",
        "negative": "24",
        "balanced": "18",
        "informational": "17",
        "total": "119"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Fox News",
        "positive": "73",
        "negative": "102",
        "balanced": "58",
        "informational": "60",
        "total": "293"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Washington Post",
        "positive": "52",
        "negative": "97",
        "balanced": "56",
        "informational": "50",
        "total": "255"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "CNN",
        "positive": "127",
        "negative": "160",
        "balanced": "102",
        "informational": "88",
        "total": "477"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "USA Today",
        "positive": "32",
        "negative": "23",
        "balanced": "14",
        "informational": "22",
        "total": "91"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "The Daily Beast",
        "positive": "9",
        "negative": "50",
        "balanced": "13",
        "informational": "10",
        "total": "82"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Bloomberg",
        "positive": "251",
        "negative": "183",
        "balanced": "158",
        "informational": "119",
        "total": "711"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Fusion",
        "positive": "48",
        "negative": "86",
        "balanced": "54",
        "informational": "49",
        "total": "237"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "NPR",
        "positive": "20",
        "negative": "30",
        "balanced": "12",
        "informational": "14",
        "total": "76"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Dallas Morning News",
        "positive": "40",
        "negative": "34",
        "balanced": "24",
        "informational": "31",
        "total": "129"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "TIME",
        "positive": "26",
        "negative": "30",
        "balanced": "17",
        "informational": "17",
        "total": "90"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Forbes",
        "positive": "97",
        "negative": "56",
        "balanced": "72",
        "informational": "37",
        "total": "262"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Christian Science Monitor",
        "positive": "19",
        "negative": "15",
        "balanced": "21",
        "informational": "7",
        "total": "62"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "NBC News",
        "positive": "23",
        "negative": "34",
        "balanced": "19",
        "informational": "22",
        "total": "98"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Huffington Post",
        "positive": "232",
        "negative": "344",
        "balanced": "219",
        "informational": "85",
        "total": "880"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "New York TImes",
        "positive": "90",
        "negative": "129",
        "balanced": "74",
        "informational": "62",
        "total": "355"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Houston Chronicle",
        "positive": "40",
        "negative": "32",
        "balanced": "31",
        "informational": "24",
        "total": "127"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Los Angeles Times",
        "positive": "66",
        "negative": "75",
        "balanced": "45",
        "informational": "45",
        "total": "231"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "San Antonio Express News",
        "positive": "28",
        "negative": "22",
        "balanced": "14",
        "informational": "16",
        "total": "80"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Arizona Daily Star",
        "positive": "32",
        "negative": "15",
        "balanced": "6",
        "informational": "8",
        "total": "61"
      }, {
        "media_outlet": "Vice News",
        "positive": "17",
        "negative": "169",
        "balanced": "44",
        "informational": "12",
        "total": "242 "
      }];

      let data = newsData.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (+a.total < +b.total) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      });

      let max = -1e9;
      data = data.map(function(d) {
        let m = Math.max(d.positive, d.negative, d.balanced, d.informational);
        if (m > max) max = m;
        return {
          key: d.media_outlet,
          values: [{
            key: 'positive',
            value: +d.positive
          }, {
            key: 'negative',
            value: +d.negative
          }, {
            key: 'balanced',
            value: +d.balanced
          }, {
            key: 'informational',
            value: +d.informational
          }]
        };
      });

      const tValues = ['positive', 'negative', 'balanced', 'informational'];
      const colors = ['#5cdacc', '#ff1d34', '#ffc750', '#ff8c50'];

      const margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 50
      };
      const width = 310 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svgs = d3
        .select('#outlets-viz')
        .selectAll('svg')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'media-svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      const color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(tValues)
        .range(['#5cdacc', '#ff1d34', '#ffc750', '#ff8c50']);

      const x = d3
        .scalePoint()
        .domain(tValues)
        .range([0, width]);

      svgs
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .attr('class', 'domain')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(
          t => t[0].toUpperCase()
        ));

      const y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, max])
        .range([height, 0]);

      const bars = svgs
        .selectAll('.bars')
        .data(function(d) {
          return d.values;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bars')
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {
          return x(d.key) - 5;
        })
        .attr('height', function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .style('fill', function(d, i) {
          return color(d.key);
        });
```

```html
<script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="outlets-viz"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark ! I'm still trying to learn my way with d3 and this is going to help me so much !